# why my if statement do not work

Tags: c, numbers

my code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    unsigned long int a,x;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n--)
    {
        scanf("%lu",&a);
        int count=0;
        while(a!=0)
        {
            x=a%10;
            printf("x=%lu\n",x );
            if(x!=4||x!=7)
            {
                count++;
            }
            printf("count =%d\n",count );
            a=a/10;
        }
        //printf("%d\n",count );
    }
}
```

I observed that when x=4 or x=7 count is incremented, it should not because I have put an if condition in it.

Comment: The if condition "if (x != 4||x != 7)" will always be True, even when x= 4 or x=7.

Comment: And why exatcly should not it be incremented? your if statment tells that if either of  `x!=7` or `x!=4` is true, then increment count. Perhaps you meant to use `&&` and not `||`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `||` with `&&` in `if` condition, otherwise the result of `x!=4||x!=7` will always be `true`.
When `x = 4` then `x != 4` is evaluated and it returns `false`, then `x != 7` is evaluated which evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question is answered, I wanted to post my answer. Might come handy to future viewers.

Try this `if(x!=4 && x!=7)` in your if condition

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    unsigned long int a,x;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n--)
    {
        scanf("%lu",&a);
        int count=0;
        while(a!=0)
        {
            x=a%10;
            printf("x=%lu\n",x );
            if(x!=4 && x!=7)
            {
            count++;
          }
            printf("count =%d\n",count );
            a=a/10;
        }
        //printf("%d\n",count );
    }
}
```